# Double indentation in Vim using python plugins

Tags: python, vim

I followed sontek's tutorial (http://sontek.net/blog/detail/turning-vim-into-a-modern-python-ide) to turn Vim into a python IDE. Unfortunatately, when there should be an identation (when pressing ENTER after : or ( ), I have both 4 spaces and a tabulation, making the indentation twice too big.

I should add that to fix Vim saying

```
Error detected while processing /home/maxime/.vim/bundle/tasklist/plugin/tasklist.vim:
line  369:
E227: mapping already exists for \t
```

I added `noremap <leader>v <Plug>TaskList` at the beginning of `.vimrc`

So my vimrc file is:

```
nnoremap <leader>v <Plug>TaskList

call pathogen#incubate()

filetype off

syntax on

filetype plugin indent on

call pathogen#helptags()
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Oh! Another victim of the "Vim as an IDE" meme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is my tab that was too long after I had removed all the plugins.
Adding

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

Solved that

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your `~/.vimrc` should look:

```
" turns filetype detection off
" before running pathogen
" because it is supposed to break
" things
filetype off

" the proper way to run pathogen
" and index your plugins documentation
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()

" turns filetype detection, ft-specific
" plugins, indent scripts and syntax
" highlighting on
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

" your custom mapping
nnoremap <leader>v <Plug>TaskList
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the use of the different lines. But doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: What plugins did you install?

Comment: All the one that were advised on the link I gave, so
fugitive, snipmate, surround, supertab, minibufexpl, command-t, ack, gundo, pydoc, pep8, py.test, makegreen, tasklist, nerdtree, ropevim

Comment: Well, remove all of them and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't you will need to bisect your plugins. Also, my answer was not merely an explanation of each line: they are in the wrong order in your vimrc and must be reordered as per my answer.

Comment: Yeah I changed the order to yours. Actually I deleted all plugins, and  still have the problem. 
If I comment the line "filetype plugin indent on" I don't have any auto-indent anymore.

Comment: Try this: 1. `$ vim -u NONE --noplugins`, 2. `:set nocp`, 3. `:filetype plugin indent on`, 4. `:syntax on`, 5. `:setf python`, 6. `idef foo():<CR>print "bar"<Esc>`. Afer you hit `<CR>`, the cursor is supposed to be automatically indented by 4 spaces.

Comment: did what you said, but not sure what you mean by <CR>. Does that mean the ENTER button? If so, the indentation is still incorrect...

Comment: Yes, `<CR>` is the enter key, see `:help key-notation`. [This screenshot](http://imgur.com/VyFN0TB) seems to be quite correct to me: 4 spaces indentation, automatic indentation after `<CR>`.

Comment: Yes, your screenshot is fine, but I still have double the normal identation. Even following your steps. I'll probably just use PyDev...